# Как просмотреть исходный код openJDK?

Tags: java, openjdk

Я загрузил openJDK 17, нашел в нем файл lib/src.zip. Распаковал его в отдельную папку
Проблема в том, что я не могу найти, где находятся библиотеки, состоящие в Java Core (например, я хочу посмотреть на код класса Math из java.lang). Как мне их найти?

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы ищите находится в папке **java.base**. Конкретно Math располагается по следующему пути:
**src.zip/java.base/lang/Math.java**

Comment: А можно прямо в вебе: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u . Там и поиск есть